# Is there any way to undertake rounding with custom rules?

Tags: r, datetime, rounding

I'm wondering if there's any way to round up or down based on my own rules, not just the basic 0.5 up or down.
The numbers I'm trying to round are in the form of 24 hour time i.e. 2250, 1100, 830 (but in numeric format), and I want to round up or down based on if the last two numbers are above or below 30 - and this is rounding up to the next hour.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can write a function to round in any way that you want.

Comment: The `lubridate` package has a function [round_date](https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/man/round_date.html) which is able to round time to the nearest hour. This is essentially what you are asking. Using this would require that you think of your data as actual times rather than integers -- but if they *are* times, why not use the R package which is best for dates and/or times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just offset the numbers before rounding them :

```
round(c(2250, 1100, 830) + 20, -2)
# [1] 2300 1100  800
```

You might want to add `%% 2400` to it :

```
round(2350 + 20, -2)
# [1] 2400
round(2350 + 20, -2) %% 2400
# [1] 0
```

So that would be :

```
round_hour <- function(x) round(x + 20, -2) %% 2400
```

Thanks @snoram for the tip

Comment: nice1. I guess you could also do `round(c(2250, 1100, 830) + 20, -2)`? Which would have fewer operations

Comment: good point, I didn't know round could take negative digits, thanks, I'll update

Answer (score 1):

Something along the line of this?

```
# Function
hround <- function(x) {
  if (any(x < 0 | x > 24000)) stop("Invalid format")
  mins <- x %% 100
  x <- x - mins + ifelse(mins >= 30, 100, 0)
  ifelse(x == 2400, 0, x)
}
# test data:
test <- c(2250, 1100, 830, 725)

# Test run
hround(test)
# [1] 2300 1100  900  700
```